# Android on Ubunto 20.04

Tags: android, emulation

I just retired from my day job and I would like to run some of the android apps  that currently are on the company phone on my Ubuntu machine.  I tried this about a year ago with anbox and it was a total failure.  I think the most important ones would be pluto TV and Tubi which would not run on anbox, but run just fine on my phone running android marshmello and they work fine on nougat also.  These apps do run on my windows box with bluestacks, but that's not the machine that I use to run my TV.

I'm looking at the possibility of waydroid. Does anyone have any experience with this or is there something better.  I'm preferring to stay away from genymotion for now due to cost.

Thanks
Steven